# How to Trigger the Event from the Droid project to Portable project Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

Suppose, I have a ScanData() function in Droid project which is triggered when I press the scan button attached in device. This function gives me scanned value of bar code whatever i scanned via Android Device (Motorola TC70).

Now is it possible to trigger the event in Portable project's XAML form on same time when it is triggering in the Droid project with the scanned value using dependency injection or something Messaging Center type class.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but I just solved this myself, so here's a solution.
You can indeed use MessagingCenter, it can be a hassle getting it to work though.
This is how I solved it:

In my App.xaml.cs I have this player object:

```
public static Interfaces.IAudioPlayer player = DependencyService.Get<Interfaces.IAudioPlayer>();
```

In my Android implementation of the interface I have this:

```
public AudioPlayerImplementation()
    {
        InitializePlayer();
        Player.Prepared += Player_Prepared;
    }
private void Player_Prepared(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Player.Start();
        MessagingCenter.Send<IAudioPlayer>(this, "PlayerPrepared");
    }
```

And in the PCL class where I want to receive the message, I have this:

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<Interfaces.IAudioPlayer>(App.player, "PlayerPrepared", (args) =>
        {
            PlayerPrepared();
        });
```

This works, took me a while to figure it out though.